# Define undefined array key in php

Tags: php, arrays, undefined

I'm using the following web to insert two codes separated by the letter "k" in just one field.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submitButton'])){
        $input=$_POST['input'];
        $explodedinput=explode('k', $input);

        echo $explodedinput[0];
        echo ' ';
        echo $explodedinput[1];
    }
?>

<form id="login" method="post">
    <input type="password" name="input">
    <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="SEND">
</form>
```

The problem comes with the user is wrong and introduces a code without "k" by mistake. Then, it appears the code ***Warning: Undefined array key 1***.

**How can I define that value when "k" is not present in the input??**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For PHP 7 and below use [`strpos`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) or [`stripos`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php). I created a function like this

```
function itContains($myString, $search, $caseSensitive = false) {
    return $caseSensitive ?
    (strpos($myString, $search) === FALSE ? FALSE : TRUE):
    (stripos($myString, $search) === FALSE ? FALSE : TRUE);
}
```

so you may use it like

```
if(isset($_POST['submitButton'])){
    $input=$_POST['input'];
    if (itContains($input, 'k')) {
      $explodedinput=explode('k', $input);
      echo $explodedinput[0]." ".$explodedinput[1];
    }
   
}
```

For PHP 8+

```
if (str_contains('How are you', 'are')) { 
    echo 'yes it contains';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $input=$_POST['input'];
    if(isset($_POST['submitButton'])){
    if (str_contains('k', $input)) {
        $explodedinput=explode('k', $input);

        echo $explodedinput[0];
        echo ' ';
        echo $explodedinput[1];
    }

 
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't work and new warning messages appear....

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the number of parts explode returns is greater than 1 if you want to index using zero and one.

You are only checking if `submitButton` is set, but you can also check if `input` is set as you are exploding on input.

```
if (isset($_POST['submitButton']) && isset($_POST['input'])) {
    $explodedinput = explode('k', $_POST['input']);
    if (count($explodedinput) > 1) {
        echo $explodedinput[0];
        echo ' ';
        echo $explodedinput[1];
    }
}
```